# Vimperator Style Extension for Safari 5?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Do we have a [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator) style extension for Safari 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the extensions by Daniel Bergey useful: http://dbergey.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not really. I've been hoping for a good one, but I keep coming back to Firefox and [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/), a Vimperator fork.

Safari does have [Vimlike](http://safariextensions.tumblr.com/post/692039154/vim-like-on-safari) and [Vim Keybindings](http://safariextensions.tumblr.com/post/683611687/post-vim-keybindings-06-10-10), but Vimperator and Pentadactyl are miles ahead in terms of features. If all you're looking for is Vim-style movement and the ability to follow links from the keyboard, those should do the trick, but I miss a lot of the deeper features that Pentadactyl offers: javascript evaluation, quicklinks, ability to yank links from the keyboard, and much, much more.

Answer (score 2):

[Vimari](https://github.com/guyht/vimari/wiki) also offers some of the keyboard shortcuts from Pentadactyl.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but it seems that the plugin [sVim](https://github.com/flipxfx/sVim) does a decent job now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at: https://github.com/flipxfx/sVim 
It's similar to cVim for Chrome.